# サイドバーにチャットが表示されていない

Tags: バグ, 完了, チャット

他のサイトではサイドバーに表示されている、 `xx People Chatting` というウィジェットが表示されていないようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

<sub>これがあれば[このサイトのチャットルーム](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17893/)にも人が増えるのではという淡い期待を込めて。</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問ページに回答2件以上があれば、今日から表示されます。

> 例：[２次元配列は不連続か？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5022/%EF%BC%92%E6%AC%A1%E5%85%83%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AF%E4%B8%8D%E9%80%A3%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%8B)

Comment: 質問ページに表示されることをすっかり忘れていましたが、これは意見が割れるような時にチャットを利用し‌​てほしい、という趣旨なのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 聞いてみると、回答が少ないとサイドバーがページ自体より長くなることが多いので、回答2件以上がないとつけないようにしたと想定しています。